# AsyncTask and JSON - Android

Tags: android, json, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-json

I'm passing id form FirstFragment to SecondFragment. I need that I'd to send POST request to web service to retrieve JSON, which I need to create content of SecondFragment. SecondFragment is ListView with custom layout. I'm adding that layout with my custom adapter class (MyAdapter). For JSON I also have AsyncTask class (GetCategoryTas) The problem is that the SecondFragment is created before service give me result back. So content is always blank. How can I fix this.

FirstFragment:

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("id", menuList.get(position).getAlias());
    categoryPage = new FragmentCategoryPage();
    categoryPage.setArguments(bundle);
    transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.mainContainer, categoryPage, "CategoryPage");
    transaction.addToBackStack("CategoryPage");
    transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    transaction.commit();

}
```

SecondFragment:

```
public class FragmentCategoryPage extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener {

    private ListView lvCategory;
    private List<NameValuePair> pair;

    private ArrayList<ItemCategory> itemCatList = new ArrayList<ItemCategory>();
    private ItemCategory itemCat;

    private MyAdapter myAdapter;
    private Context context;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_category, container, false);

        context = getActivity();

        String id = getArguments().getString("id");
        pair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        pair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("category", id));
        new GetCategoryTask().execute();

        lvCategory = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvCategory);

        myAdapter = new MyAdapter();
        lvCategory.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        lvCategory.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        return view;
    }

    // Creating own adapter for categories
    class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        @Override
        public View getView(final int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = null;

            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout_category, parent, false);
            } else {
                row = convertView;
            }

            TextView tvCatTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvCategoryTitle);
            TextView tvCatDate = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvCategoryDate);
            ImageView ivCatImage = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.ivCategoryImage);

            return row;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() { return itemCatList.size(); }
        @Override
        public Object getItem(int pos) { return null; }
        @Override
        public long getItemId(int pos) { return 0; }
    }

    public class GetCategoryTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(Variables.URL_CATEGORY);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pair));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

                int status = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

                if (status == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {

                    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(data);
                    for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject jRealObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        itemCat = new ItemCategory();
                        itemCat.setId(jRealObject.get("id").toString());
                        itemCat.setTitle(jRealObject.get("title").toString());
                        itemCat.setImage_name(jRealObject.get("image_name").toString());

                        itemCatList.add(itemCat);
                    }

                    return true;
                }
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if(result == false) {
                Toast.makeText(context, Variables.ERROR_MESSAGE, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should refresh your adapter in `onPostExecute()` by calling;

```
myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo man THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! :D I was stuck with tihs sh*t whole day :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I dont see anywhere in your code that you have connected your listview with the itemCatList. And you should do anything you wanna do with your listview in onPostExecute, not in onCreate, so you could be sure that the list exists in that point as AsyncTask runs on its own thread 
in onPostExecute

```
 lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.your_list_view_id);
 List<String> your_array_list = new ArrayList<String>();
 ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
         this, 
         android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
         your_array_list );

 lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Comment: I have custom adapter with custom layout, in which I'm doing that :)